# What is the relation between Java and XML in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I recently started learning Android, after learning a little bit of Java concepts. Before getting into Android, I had no idea about what XML is, and I am having a hard time of making codes. What I only know about XML is that it stands for external markup language. Is it right to say that, in Android, it is Java that tells the computer to do certain kinds of tasks, and XML provides the 'materials' needed for the task process?

Comment: In Android you use xml to provide layouts and other resources used by your java files.

Comment: probably best to ask in Programmers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That on a very basic interpretation is exactly the relation between Java and XML. 
Another example would be a Java based Testfactory for your Integration tests that uses xml-based descriptions.

Based on this imagine a XML in this direction:

```
<Testset>
    <Testcase>
        <Name>Somketest</Name>
        <TestInstructions>
            <ClassesUnderTest>
             ....
            </ClassesUnderTest>
        </TestInstructions>
    </Testcase>
</Testset>
```

May lead to your Testfactory generating classes/ mocks etc. based on this information.

Another case may just need your Testfactory to provide Java object representations of requests to a Server to automaticially marshall the according XML into the object world.

In general XML will provide you with "information" while Java has logic to handle this information.

**NOTE:** The context as faar as i see it counts for the relation between XML and XSLT as well with the difference the output of the transformation (usning XSLT) will again be XML (so can it be using Java..).

Answer (score 0):

In android XML file is used to represent layout e.g 
activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and to show this layout on android screen we write following line in java class Mainactivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    **setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);**

}
```